# Equal Column Height on Hidden Elements

Tags: jquery

I have 2 columns (left and right), that I want equal columns. The code used below does this perfectly. However, on column left I have some hidden text/paragraphs that can be seen by clicking a button, which would then reveal the hidden content. The code I'm using doesn't account for the extra height, it just overlaps.

What modification to the code should I make to account for the extra height when hidden content is revealed?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="blocks left">
        <button>Show</button>

        <div class="hidden-content">
             Yup!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocks right"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    columns.each(function() {
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
            tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
        }
    });
    columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}

setEqualHeight( $('.blocks'));
```

Comment: Call `setEqualHeight` again on hiding/revealing.

Comment: Still the same. The hidden content overlaps the content below.

Comment: Does the container get new height after the hidden div is revealed?

Comment: No, it stays the same. When calling setEqualHeight on the hidden element, the height of the hidden element is the same as .blocks.left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before revealing/hiding the content reset the height that was added to the container `.blocks` to `auto'. Earlier the height was fixed(on initial calculation) so any content added would overlap.

JS

```
//on click of the button
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.blocks').css("height", "auto");
    $('.hidden-content').show();
    setEqualHeight($('.blocks'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/sgauu4jh/1/)

Comment: Here's the weird thing. I'm using slideToggle to hide and show the content. When I click, it doesn't work, but when I click to close it adds the new height. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Is this similar to what you have done? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/sgauu4jh/2/)

Comment: From your Fiddle, I basically did slideToggle rather than show. If you change show to slideToggle, you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I was not resetting the variable `tallestcolumn` inside the function. [Check this now](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/sgauu4jh/4/)

Comment: I appreciate all the help man. One last question, how do I reset the height of the .left, when I close the hidden content?

Comment: I am already resetting it in my last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/sgauu4jh/4/)